# React Native: Is there an easy way to update all object values if given value exists already?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, javascript-objects

I'm trying to work with data using Flatlist/Sectionlist, etc... but I'm trying to see how I can manipulate my data set if a given value already exists?

Say a user passes in a link into my form, and this link is already in the dataset, I want to be able to update all its related property values:

I've used to work a little bit regarding database systems like mongodb, where you can just update based on the id, but because this isn't a full fledge data system, I'm not exactly sure the path to take. It may very well be something simple where I'm just having brain fog...

```
const storedData = [
  {
    url: 'google.com'
    username: 'usernametag',
    content: 'this is some content that will go on forever and ever',
    thumbnail: 'https://url.jpg',
    avatar: 'https://url.jpg',
    media: 'https://url.mp4',
  },
  {
    url: 'sample.com'
    username: 'name',
    content: 'lost content goals lets start with some content forever and ever before we can start ending this hopefully it will last forever',
    thumbnail: 'https://url.jpg',
    avatar: 'https://url.jpg',
    media: 'https://url.mp4',
  },
  {
    url: 'thisisurl.com'
    username: 'another name',
    content: 'lost content goals lets start with some content forever and ever before we can start ending this hopefully it will last forever',
    thumbnail: 'https://url.jpg',
    avatar: 'https://url.jpg',
    media: 'https://url.mp4',
  },
];
```

So if the user submits data, and `google.com` already exists, how do I grab that specific block of objects and update everything within it?

I was able to check to see if google.com exists by doing this:

```
if (!JSON.stringify(storedData).includes('google.com'))
```

Then I would like to be able to update `username`, `content`, `thumbnail`, `avatar`, `media`

But I'm not too sure that this would be the best way to do so?

Comment: at the end of the day, you have to loop over every object and check for its url type, and includes does the same in the back of the hood. So i believe you are doing right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find() method in JS

```
const storedData = [
    {
      url: 'google.com',
      username: 'usernametag',
      content: 'this is some content that will go on forever and ever',
      thumbnail: 'https://url.jpg',
      avatar: 'https://url.jpg',
      media: 'https://url.mp4',
    },
    {
      url: 'sample.com',
      username: 'name',
      content: 'lost content goals lets start with some content forever and ever before we can start ending this hopefully it will last forever',
      thumbnail: 'https://url.jpg',
      avatar: 'https://url.jpg',
      media: 'https://url.mp4',
    },
    {
      url: 'thisisurl.com',
      username: 'another name',
      content: 'lost content goals lets start with some content forever and ever before we can start ending this hopefully it will last forever',
      thumbnail: 'https://url.jpg',
      avatar: 'https://url.jpg',
      media: 'https://url.mp4',
    },
  ];

let selectedObj = storedData.find(item => item.url == 'google.com')

selectedObj.username = 'hello'

console.log(storedData)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `map` and in the callback function you can check for the url and return a new object if it matches.

```
let newStoredData = storedData.map(urlObject => { 
    if (urlObject.url === "google.com") {
     return {/*new object*/}
    }
    else
     return urlObject
    }
  )
```